# Querying records based on max of subcollection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As the title says, for example we have a library system with two tables `Books` and `RentalRecord` with a one to many relationship. It looks like

```
Book1
--name
--RentalRecords
----record11
----record12
Book2
--name
--RentalRecords
----record21
----record22
----record23
----record24
```

Each record contains 2 time stamps for date rented, and date returned

and I want to query for the Books that hasn't been rented out in the past 2 weeks.
I'm new to Ruby and couldn't think of any way to do this without using multiple queries.

Comment: Please show the models and the table definitions (from the migrations) for `Books` and `RentalRecord`.

Comment: Is this good enough?

Comment: That's not it.  You need to post the contents of the `app/book.rb` and `app/rental_record.rb` files, as well as the migrations in `db/migrate` that include the `create_table` calls for `:books` and `:rental_record`.

Answer (score 0):

Using two queries sometimes is a viable option. If you prefer constructing a single query, use something along the lines of

`Book.joins(:rental_records)
     .where("max(rental_records.created_at) < ?", 2.weeks.ago)`

Things to note:

- You need to join the required tables explicitly (but by association name)
- You can use a plain string in a Rails `where` statement
- You can bind a Ruby value to a question mark within such a string

If your queries get out of hand or you don't like using plain SQL strings like that, then take a look at the gem [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel). It provides an fully-fledged SQL algebra for Ruby on Rails.

HTH

Comment: I agree with Michael that knowing a bit more about your code would have helped to come up with an answer that fits perfectly. Add the `db/schema.rb` to the shopping cart :)